# Symfony2: fetching all translations under a parent

Tags: php, symfony, translation, yaml

In symfony2 controller you can fetch a specific translation using:
    `$this->get('translator')->trans('dropdown.state.CA.AB');`

Example `messages.en.yml`:

```
dropdown:
    state:
        CA:
            AB: Alberta
            BC: British Columbia
            MB: Manitoba
```

How can I fetch AB, BC and MB in one single call (in an array maybe) and hopefully also be able to call it individually using the above or a similar translation call.

Couple of things I have tried:

`$this->get('translator')->trans('zuora.dropdown.state.CA);`

```
dropdown:
    state:
        CA:
            - AB: Alberta
            - BC: British Columbia
            - MB: Manitobavarious
```

Surely, missing some step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot get it through the translator.
This is because of [`ArrayLoader`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Loader/ArrayLoader.html)  [**flattens**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Loader/ArrayLoader.php#L32) the result of the parsed yml.

Flatten method transforms inputs like

```
Array (
    [foo] => Array(
        [bar] => baz
        [sub] => Array(
            [fiz] => foobaz
        )
    )
)
```

To

```
Array (
    [foo.bar] => baz
    [foo.sub.fiz] => foobaz
)
```

The only way I could find, is to parse again the translation file.

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

// From a controller
$file   = __DIR__.'/../Resources/translations/messages.en.yml';
$parsed = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));

foreach ($parsed['dropdown']['state']['CA'] as $ca => $content) {
    // Your logic...
}
```